# Undefined index for params

Tags: php, magento

I have this code in PHP

```
$customer->setGroupId($params['group_id']);
```

I get undefined index group_id error when I run it.
I want that if it is undefined then do not throw error but continue the code to work.

How is it possible?

Comment: Use `$params['group_id'] ?? null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with isset() function, for example:

```
if(isset($params['group_id']) {
   $customer->setGroupId($params['group_id']);
}else {
   // Something
}
```

If you want to check for the empty field, you should use empty() function too:

```
if(!empty($params['group_id']) {
   $customer->setGroupId($params['group_id']);
}else {
   // Something
}
```